# update from 20.04 to 22.04: problem

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kernel, 22.04, removing

When upgrading from 20 to 22 I always have a package that is not updated:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  ntp
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **1** not upgraded.
```

Then when I do:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3 -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

It did not do it because it is asking to install all available updates. This circular, because I have already done update and upgrade. When I tried:

```
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
ntp/focal-updates,focal-security 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu3]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

The focal-security seems the problem. I don't know how to overcome this problem and get the version 22.04 LTS.. Any Help is welcome.

Comment: `sudo apt install --only-upgrade ntp` Then try again.